# Solving linear equation of 2x2 vector matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra

In studying linear independence, I came across this material in my notes:

[image: Formula]

Where the goal is basically to show that the vectors (the 2x2 matrixes) are linearly independent).

However, I'm unsure how/why there's a $c_3$ in there. As I understand it, it'd be:

$c_1\pmatrix{1 \\0} + c_2\pmatrix{4 \\ 0}=\pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$

$c_1\pmatrix{2 \\-1} + c_2\pmatrix{1 \\ -3}=\pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$

And so it should be $-c_1-3c_2=0$, but I clearly misunderstood something. I think what I'm missing is how to 'translate' the 2x2 vector equation into system equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, the $c_3$ is a typo (it should be replaced by $c_2$).

We need to show that the system in $c_1$ and $c_2$ has only the trivial solution that is $c_1=c_2=0$.

Comment: Thank you! This is the first time it came up in the material so I had to verify it somehow. I'll accept the answer once the 5 minute accept timer is up.

Comment: @Secret You are welcome! Bye